# How to give if else condition in asp.net c# inside grid template?

Tags: c#, asp.net, c#-4.0

I have written like below lines of code

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Marketing Document / URL" SortExpression="DocumentActualName">
                 <ItemTemplate>
                  <%# (String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("DocumentActualName").ToString() ) ? %>
                 <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownload" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval (Container.DataItem, "ProductDocument") %>'
                  CommandName="Download" CausesValidation="false" Text='<%# Eval("DocumentActualName") %>'> </asp:LinkButton>
                  <% : %>
                  <a id ="lnkUrl" runat="server" href='<%# Eval("URL") %>' Text='<%# Eval("URL") %>'></a> 
                  </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
```

It's not working. Please help

Comment: Can not write in separate line

Comment: Can u please provide me syntax for writting the above code in if else condition. i have tried a lot but failed.

Comment: I have updated my question.. this is the exact code

Comment: It is throwing error message invalid term ':'

Answer (score 0):

You need to bring the databinding tags (<%#) outside of the Page.ResolveUrl method, and use single quotes around the href attribute:

```
href='<%#Page.ResolveUrl(Eval("URL"))%>'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href='<%# String.IsNullOrEmpty(Eval("File").ToString()) ? Eval("URL") : Eval("File") %>'> URL </a>
```